# Club sets of $\omega_1$ have the same order type as $\omega_1$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

This is a short lemma that I've come up with that I need to prove in a solution to a homework problem. I'm sure that it's true, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

What I need to do is show that if $C \subset \omega_1$ is club, then there is an increasing bijection $f:\omega_1 \to C$.

So I should try to inductively construct this $f$. So for $0$, define $f(0) = \inf(C)$. Then, for each $\alpha + 1\in \omega_1$, define $f(\alpha +1) = \inf\{ C \setminus \{f(\beta) : \beta < \alpha\}\}$. Then if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal, define $f(\lambda) = \sup\{ f(\beta): \beta < \lambda\}$. Since $C$ is closed, $f(\lambda) \in C$.

Does this construction work?

Comment: Yes, though depending on your instructor you might want to mention explicitly that $\sup\{f(\beta):\beta<\lambda\}<\omega_1$, so the construction does not terminate prematurely.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ok, thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That works but it's unnecessarily complicated. In fact **every unbounded subset $S$ of $\omega_1$ has the same ordertype as $\omega_1$.**

To see this we use a simpler version of your bijection: recursively set $f(\alpha)=\min(S\setminus \{f(\beta): \beta<\alpha\})$ for **all** $\alpha<\omega_1$, successor or limit.

By induction together with the fact that $S$ is unbounded you can prove that for all $\alpha<\omega_1$ the ordinal $f(\alpha)$ exists (that is, $S\setminus \{f(\beta): \beta<\alpha\}$ is nonempty and so has a minimal element) and is $<\omega_1$; this uses as a key step the fact that [every countable subset of $\omega_1$ is bounded below $\omega_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_cardinal), which is a good exercise.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you.